# How to specify RAM and CPU amount to be used for a cloudlet in CloudSim?

Tags: java, cloud, cloudsim

I want to specify by myself the amount of CPU and RAM for my task.For example, I want my first task to consume CPU X and RAM Y and the other consume CPU Z and RAM Z, now how to do that in CloudSim?

Comment: It seems like you might get a better recommendation on Server Fault, although I suspect the docs probably cover this.

Comment: Thank  u. There is the UtilisationModel interface but i did not know how to employ it in my context.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudlet(
            final int cloudletId,

```
        final long cloudletLength,
        final int pesNumber,
        final long cloudletFileSize,
        final long cloudletOutputSize,
        final UtilizationModel utilizationModelCpu,
        final UtilizationModel utilizationModelRam,
        final UtilizationModel utilizationModelBw)
```

In cloudsim, the cpu usage is represented as PEs, defined in terms of MIPS rating. The 'cloudletLength' is in MI unit, so if you set the utilization model for CPU as 'full' and change the cloudlet length, I believe you can change the amount of cpu use accordingly. Also, the file size may be changed to change the RAM. Set the utilization model for Ram as 'full'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . My goal is to specify the percentage of cpu used and the amount of memory because i'm going to classify tasks as cpu intensive and memory intensive etc . so i need to predefine the resource usage of my task according to my context.